# How to change the List Text colors in windows phone7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I submitted my Wp7 app but it was rejected for the reason is

```
   Application content, such as text and visual
   elements, must be visible and legible regardless of
   the phone theme. For example, if the phone
   theme changes from black background to white
   background, the text and visual elements of your
   application must be visible or legible.
```

### Test Process Required:

```
    1. Navigate to the Settings page in the app list.
    2. Tap theme and change Background to 'Dark'.
    3. Launch the application.
    4. Verify that the text and visual elements of the
         application are visible and legible.
    5. Navigate back to the theme page under
           Settings, and change Background to 'Light'
    6. Launch the application.
    7. Verify that the text and visual elements of the
       application are visible and legible.
```

actually i am using ListBox in my Xmal page in that i have set baground color Block and font color is white. How to change Font color that when they Change Device Background color in Window phone7..please help me..How to resolve this ..

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code your back and foreground colors in XAML or you could use the WindowsPhone Color resources.

[MSDN Windows Phone Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_ColorResources)

To Solve this i showed a MessageBox to the User the first time he starts the application that the app is using his location and what the app is doing with it. Then you need to give an option in the application somewhere to turn the using of his location completely off, i added this to my apps settings page. And you could provide information about why you using location in a separate page and have the setting to turn it on and off there.

The MessageBox and the Turn off setting works my app got certified like this.

Comment: Hi i have one more error   The following requirements apply to applications
that receive the location of a user's mobile device:
2.7.2 The privacy policy of your application must
inform users about how location data from the
Location Service API is used and disclosed and the
controls that users have over the use and sharing
of location data. This can be hosted within or
directly linked from the application.

Comment: @Victor Updated my answer with a suggestion to solve your error.